# When does "1..10" make sense?

Tags: syntax

I have a vague memory of a programming language where `1..10` meant "the range 1 inclusive to 10 exclusive", similar to python's `range(1, 10)`, but I haven't the foggiest *which*, and this doesn't particularly lend itself to searches. Any help?

If the answer's "python", please forgive me. I know very little python.

Comment: Python does not use that syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html) does it.

Comment: yay, that's the one I was thinking of! It's a pity I can't accept all the answers, though. Oh well, an upvote each will do.

Answer (score 6):

Pascal supports that syntax. You can actually use this as a type, and I believe it's also used in specifying array bounds. (I'm not sure how much of this is standard Pascal and how much is Turbo Pascal extensions.)

Comment: It's actually standard Pascal, not just a Borland extension.

Comment: @Paul Thanks. I thought it might be, but wasn't sure. The only Pascal I'd ever used was Turbo Pascal, and that was a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

It is Perl, called the "Range Operator"

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node38.html

Answer (score 3):

Groovy uses this syntax, too.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections

Answer (score 3):

F#, they are called Sequence Expressions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx (select the F# examples to see the code)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby!

Comment: -1 Ruby doesn't do the "exclusive" part for the last component. Although `1...10` does (one extra period).

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP already got the answer they were looking for, and this has kind of become a list of languages that use 1..n syntax, I'll add one more.

[Maple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_%28software%29)

The wiki page shows a good example

```
myfac := n -> product( i, i=1..n );
```

Note however that this is 1 to 10 *inclusive*

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has VERY similar syntax...

You can read more here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html

Comment: But you can pass exclusive as an option.  Don't think my answer deserved a downvote on that technicality.


"If the third parameter is omitted or is false, the range will include the end object; otherwise, it will be excluded. "

Comment: True if syntax used was objectified instead of using syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a vague and distant memory, then I'd guess that Pascal or Delphi is the most likely candidate for the language you're thinking of.

It's most commonly used in Pascal in a `case` statement. See here for example syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Pascal

It could also be any of a number of other languages that use this syntax, but without knowing a bit more about your programming history, my guess would still be Pascal / Delphi.